# Is Unity EventSystem pixelDragThreshold inconsistent between PC and mobile?

Tags: unity

I've noticed that when I change the resolution setting in Unity on Windows/Mac/Linux, pixelDragThreshold still seems to respect the monitor resolution rather than Unity's resolution setting.

However, when I change resolution on mobile (again, using the Unity SetResolution API), the pixelDragThreshold is affected.

I don't quite understand the relationship between Unity's resolution, screen resolution, and pixelDragThreshold.

Can someone explain how this works?  How it's supposed to work?  I'm baffled.